WCF call fails when user is not in domain admin group
I have an application running on a server (Windows server 2012) that does a wcf call to another application running on a computer(Windows 10).
The wcf call fails everytime when the user running the application is NOT a member of domain admins with this error :

(Inner Exception #0) System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---> System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)

When I add the user in the domain admins group, everything works perfectly.
Do I miss something ? Is there a security rule somewhere I'm not aware of?
Thanks in advance for your expertise.

Usually you need to be under the same domain to access it. If you need cross-domain communication, you can try using webHttpBinding and webHttp behavior. More operations require you to provide some code and configuration.

I am in the same domain and I'm currently using netTcpBinding over webHttpBinding. Could it be a problem?

It is not possible to judge at this time, and you will need to provide more material to reproduce the problem.

I found where the problem was. Someone configured a GPO to restrict the amount of groups that can access the computer from the network.
Only Administrator where allowed to access this computer.
To solve this problem, I created a group only for the right users and added this group inside the GPO of the computers I needed access to.
